BeanCreationException - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
I have recently learning Spring to be specific Spring ORM. I am getting some errors from my code, I am not getting where I am going wrong though i have all instruction of the tutorial.
Here are java and configuration files:
com.spring.orm.Main.java file
package com.spring.orm;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.spring.orm.dao.StudentDao;
import com.spring.orm.entities.Student;

public class Main 
{
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("XML/config.xml");
        StudentDao obj1 = context.getBean("studentDao",StudentDao.class);
        
        Student s1 = new Student(1,"Sudheer Mishra","Surat");
        
        int insert = obj1.insert(s1);
        if(insert > 0) {
            System.out.println("data successfully inserted");
        }System.out.println("something went wrong");
        
    }
}

com.spring.orm.entities.Student.java file


package com.spring.orm.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_details")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "studentId")
    private int studentId;

    @Column(name = "studentName")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "studentCity")
    private String studentCity;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    public Student(int studentId, String studentName, String studentCity) {
        super();
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentCity() {
        return studentCity;
    }

    public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
        this.studentCity = studentCity;
    }

}

com.spring.orm.dao.StudentDao.java file
package com.spring.orm.dao;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;

import com.spring.orm.entities.Student;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

public class StudentDao {
    
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
    
    @Transactional
    public int insert(Student student) {
        int i = (int) this.hibernateTemplate.save(student);
        /* HibernateTemplate has all the CRUD operation methods */
        return i;
    }

    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }
    
}

config.xml (which i have kept in src/main/resources/XML folder)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="all_schema_url_not adding because of question spam error">


    <!-- for enabling all annotations in spring... -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven />


    <!-- data source bean -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        name="ds">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cwdPrac" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="Root" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Local session factory bean -->
    <bean name="factory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <!-- data source -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
        <!-- hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Annonated classes -->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.spring.orm.entities.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <!-- Hibernate template bean for Dao class -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate"
        name="hibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>
    </bean>


    <!--Dao class -> data access object layer -->
    <bean class="com.spring.orm.dao.StudentDao" name="studentDao">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>
    <!-- This is our Bottom-Up approach from DAO->HibernateTemplate->Local Session 
        Factory Bean->Data Source Bean -->


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>

When I am running my Main.java I'm getting on my console
"Aug 06, 2024 6:04:25 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [XML/config.xml]: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/ClassFormatException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [XML/config.xml]: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/ClassFormatException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.spring.orm.Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/ClassFormatException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassFormatException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 15 more

I had checked what I can but not able to come up with this error, not getting that what I am missing here.
Is there any jars which I have not added ? or another configuration is still pending..
If anyone have any idea please help.
Eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build id: 20230907-1323
Thank you
If anyone have any idea, I'll be grateful for their help. I'm getting that what I am missing here any jars or configuration of my entities. But I have followed exact same path as the tutorial. But still getting this error on console.

My guess, you aren't using something like maven to manage your dependencies but have downloaded individual jars and added them to the classpath (or even random mixed versions). Don't do things like that in the current day and age, instead use a build tool like Maven or Gradle.

If you have a complex setup as in @M.Deimnum or else some versions are probably incompatible or not downloaded.
